# Does Spring ResponseEntity load the full data from a Resource into Memory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm writing a method that needs to return PDF files from another Webserver:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(String document) throws Exception {
        
        String file = "http://blabla.com?document=" + document;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + document);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
        
        UrlResource u = new UrlResource(new URL(file));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(u);
    }
```

This seems to work. The PDFs can get quite big however, and Im not entirely sure how `ResponseEntity.body()` reads and writes the file.

Is the full data being read into memory here? If so, how do I manage to make it stream it instead?

I know how to do it using HttpServletResponse and writing to outputstream, but I was wondering if Spring already takes care of this here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring takes care of this for you. A `Resource` response is streamed to the client by reading from the resource's input stream and writing to the response's output stream. If you'd like to look at the code, [this is done in `ResourceHttpMessageConverter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/8fc744f4f4bb27bba10532264a257677d2c35802/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java#L132-L156).